# run-time error '1004': Autofilter method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have used a small code in vba which gives me this error::

```
Dim today As Date
Dim Mon As Integer

today = VBA.Date()
Mon = Month(today)

Sheets("Birthday List").Activate
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter , Field:=3, Criteria1:=Mon, Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True
```

Could you please help me how to correct it

regards
Anna Smith

Comment: The only things I'm seeing immediately is "Autofilter , Field" where that ", " isn't needed and the criteria might need to be "=Mon".

Comment: I'm getting same error but I'm also working on a brand new computer using Excel 2016 for the very first time so not sure I can be much help (this is also causing my Excel to freeze and do other weird stuff, which is beyond unexpected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in your code are:

1. What @Cyril said in comments with update from @DavidZemens

> `"Autofilter , Field"` where that ", " isn't needed and the criteria might need to be `"=" & Mon`

2. You cannot set manually `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True`, but it's set automatically when calling `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter ...`. You can only set `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False` to turn the AutoFilter off.

Comment: The comma will raise a wildly different runtime error (object has disconnected from its client). The criteria *might* need to be `"=" & Mon` bot definitely not the literal string `"=Mon"` :)

Comment: Hi all,                                                                                                  ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:"=" & Mon , Operator:=xlFilterValues .................gives me a compiler error

Comment: Should be rather `Criteria1:="=" & Mon`. You want to have `"=" & Mon` as a value of criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is already resolved (it's years old) but I had a similar error '1004': Autofilter method of range class failed today and it turned out that the data I was supposed to be filtering was in a table and that borked it.  (The user who sends the report changed how they send it)

De-tabling the data (Convert Table to Range) resolved my issue.  Maybe this will help someone else.